# Application Error - The connection to the server was unsuccessful.

Tags: android, cordova

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed"  >
        <div data-role="navbar" data-position="fixed">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="index.html#main_menu"  rel="external"  data-icon="home">Home</a>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

When i try this code in my phonegap application i get following error .I know this could be possible dupliacate.(It works perfectly in Samsung tab But not in Huwavi )

```
Application Error - The connection to the server was unsuccessful. (file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by your App timing out. You can increase the time-out value,in your Application 
add this line to the java class before before loading your app url.

```
super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 60000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to increase "loadUrlTimeoutValue"

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrlTimeoutValue = 15000;
        loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
            appView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        appView.getSettings().setNavDump(false);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be caused by trying to debug. I had a weinre link in index.html that couldn't see my server - I removed it and the problem seemed to go away. In fact, any attempt to load an unavailable asset is likely to cause a timeout.